# Is it possible to draw this picture without lifting the pen or tracing?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

We got a challenge from our maths teacher and would win a prize if we were the first to get this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkfyJ.jpg)

To draw this without lifting the pen and without tracing the same line more than once.

Year 8-9 maths

**EDIT : Teacher said that the shortest time for a student took 2 days while the longest was 2 weeks so apparently it must be possible**

Answer (score 4):

Since, this is a prize problem I won't give you a solution; also you won't appreciate it(year 8-9 maths) . But I can tell you how you should think. Have a look at this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg

Answer (score 1):

There are four crossings of lines, at each meet three lines. If you look closely at one of those crossings, then when you arrive at the crossing by one line and leave by another, there is exactly one line leading to this crossing that remains to be drawn. But that means next time you arrive at this crossing, you have to stay there (you have to end your drawing), because there is no line you can use to continue (all three of them are drawn).

So even if you start at one crossing, that would still leave you with three crossings such that at each one you have to end. But you can only end once, so this is not possible.

Reaction to **EDIT**: In that case take a paint, draw the third of a circle with two lines leading to the center and fold the paper twice, each time along one of the lines. The rest of the picture should imprint on the paper after these folds. Or use any other way using "copying" of what you draw or are about to draw. But except these dirty tricks, there is no other way, but I will gladly see the solution to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this trace is not possible because the graph is not [Eulerian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path): it has $4$ vertices with odd degree (the number of edges incident to the vertex).

I understand that this answer is not a satisfactory response for Year 8-9 maths, but I encourage you to watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXPPiPGWgSs).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sort of hint/guide:

Assuming you're not allowed to "fold over" and edge of the paper and draw on the back for a little while while" as a way to skip from one location to another (i.e., not only must you draw the figure, but the figure must be ALL that you draw!), then the answer is that it's not possible. The arc you draw must have either 2 ends or 0 ends (if it starts and ends in the same place).

In the second case, if it starts and ends mid-segment (a segment being either one of the arcs or the radii), then you could solve the corresponding problem with that arc or radius deleted, and with a two-end path. So go ahead and draw THAT picture, too.

In the 2-end case, think about where the ends have to be.